# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: GraphicsLayer is not a constructor

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

```
import Map from "esri/Map";
import MapView from "esri/views/MapView";
import Graphic from "esri/Graphic";
import GraphicsLayer from "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer";
import webMercatorUtils from "esri/geometry/support/webMercatorUtils";


async function kewlClickHandler(event) {

    function initDrawLine();

        function initDrawLine(Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, webMercatorUtils) {

          const map = view.map;

          var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer(); // here
          map.add(graphicsLayer);

          ...... etc
```

No matter how I arrange my function params and header module includes; I repeatedly get the following error with my `initDrawLine` function:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: GraphicsLayer is not a constructor**

*New to arcgis-js-api, any ideas?*

---

**Update**: This is the context, no errors or issues within stand alone [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camerondevcam/pen/BayJPQo?editors=0011):
in arcgis-js 4.13

But errors in actual environment in arcgis 4.11 - confusing.

Answer (score 0):

var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer(); <--- The error us being thrown from this line of code, because as the error is saying "GraphicsLayer is not a constructor." And in that line of code, you are trying to declare GraphicsLayer as a constructor once you put () after.

Below is how you need to declare a new GraphicsLayer:

new GraphicsLayer()

Creates a new GraphicsLayer object. (Added at v1.4)

Sample:

require([
  "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", ... 
], function(GraphicsLayer, ... ) {
  var countyLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
  ...
});

Comment: For your reference: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html

Comment: Thanks for taking a look but confused with your answer: I am declaring 'new GraphicsLayer()' the same way you are in your sample

Comment: But is also has a require. I would try is exactly as it is above. Yes, there is a function, but it is all included inside the parens of the require.